# Optional term in ContentSearch query

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I'm trying to build a lucene query through Sitecore ContentSearch that includes an optional term. The optional term is used to boost certain results. The lucene query should look like this:

```
+(+(_content:myquery keywords:myquery) boostfield:boostdata)
```

How can I construct such a query? With PredicateBuilder I can only add And / Or expressions.

Here's an example of how I construct the predicate:

```
var contentPredicate = PredicateBuilder.Create<MySearchResultItem>(p => p.Content == parameters.QueryString);

contentPredicate = contentPredicate.Or(k => k.Keywords == "myquery");

mainPredicate = mainPredicate.And(contentPredicate);

mainPredicate = mainPredicate.And(f => f["boostfield"] == "boostdata");
```

This will make "boostfield" a *must* field wich is not what I need (note the + before the field name):

```
+(+(_content:myquery keywords:myquery) +boostfield:boostdata)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried this:
 mainPredicate.Or(f => f["boostfield"] == "boostdata")

Comment: No, that won't do the job. I managed to work around the problem by building a statement like (contentPredicate AND boostfield) OR contentPredicate.

Comment: Mark, I played around with a bunch of different combinations and the approach you mention in the comment above is the best I was able to find as well.  Both Lucene and SOLR are not keeping the grouping you'd expect when you OR all the terms together, even in separate predicates.

Comment: I find sometimes adding an additional predicate provides the expected results. sometimes when combining all parameters in one predicate things dont work as you would expect and becomes very difficult to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var contentPredicate = PredicateBuilder.Create<MySearchResultItem>(p => p.Content == parameters.QueryString);

contentPredicate = contentPredicate.Or(k => k.Keywords == "myquery");

mainPredicate = mainPredicate.And(contentPredicate);

var boostQuery = PredicateBuilder.False<MySearchResultItem>();
boostQuery = boostQuery.Or(f => f["boostfield"] == "boostdata");

mainPredicate = mainPredicate.Or(boostQuery)
```

I think it could get you the results you need.

Comment: Ahmed, unfortunately Sitecore isn't keeping the grouping you would expect with this code and you end up with just OR'd statements which isn't what Mark was looking for.  The lucene query ends up something like  (content:searchQuery keywords:keywordQuery boostField:boostdata) instead of grouped as you would expect with the separate predicate.  I'm not sure if this is a bug or as expected but it might be worth opening a ticket with Sitecore to find out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply looking to boost results based on an optional field, you can have your predicate builder as follows:

```
boostfield.contains("term") or field.contains("term")
```

And then increase the boost value in the standard fields for the field item itself. The order in which you build the predicate has a bearing on the results so make sure you check against the boost field first.